# How do I install Ubuntu Server without a CD drive?

Tags: installation, server

I see no instructions for it and the iso file doesn't work on a jump drive..?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the Server ISO can be "burned" to a USB and will work similarly.

Please download the appropriate ISO, and [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sf.net), and use Unetbootin to prepare the USB jumpdrive. Then boot from it and you should get the below screen:

[image]

Comment: Is that to say that the alternate ISO (and Debian ISO's) are *still* not hybrid CD/USB? If so, why would the server ISO be hybrid, but the alternate ISO not? I seem to recall successfully booting from a USB flash drive with the mini ISO written to it, but I'm not sure...

Comment: @EliahKagan, you're right IIRC, I was thinking about 10.04 Alternate; 12.04 Alternate *should* be hybrid and boot from a USB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a flash drive as media to install Ubuntu, you can use tool like [lili usb creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/).